# How come I can't pass any calculations and variables I define in ViewDidAppear/ViewDidLoad with preparetosegue method? And how can I achieve this?

Tags: ios, swift

Exactly, as title. I started by putting my HTTP request session in the viewdidload, until I realized it was a terrible place to put it, as it's way low in the hierarchy of methods called, and essentially it was hopeless to define variables there to pass to another VC.

However, I switched to Viewdidappear, but I still get nil, when I pass the variables through prepareforsegue. Is there another method I can use, or how do you suggest I achieve what I want? I could possibly post request whenever i press a button, that would surely pass variables down?

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    activityIndicatorView.startAnimating()
}

override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {

    super.viewDidAppear(animated)

    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: "http://127.0.0.1:5000")!)
    request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
    let postString = "color=\(self.finalDataPassed)&location=\(self.thirdDataPassed)&weather=\(self.dataPassed)&city=\(self.secondDataPassed)"

    request.HTTPBody = postString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
    let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(request) {
        data, response, error in

        if error != nil {
            println("error=\(error)")
            return
        }

        println("response = \(response)")

        let responseString = NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)

        println(responseString)
        var error: NSError?

        let result = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error: &error) as? NSDictionary

        var dict: NSDictionary = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error: nil) as! NSDictionary


        if(error != nil) {
            println(error!.localizedDescription)
            let jsonStr = NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
            println("Error could not parse JSON: '\(jsonStr)'")
        }
        else {
            if let results = result?.valueForKey("result") as? NSArray {
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
                    println(results)
                })
            }

            let parseJSON: AnyObject? = result!.valueForKey("result")
            var stuff: AnyObject! = parseJSON!.valueForKey("price")
            var otherstuff: NSString! = parseJSON!.valueForKey("YlowestURL") as! NSString
        }

        self.activityIndicatorView.stopAnimating()
    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("calculateToDisplaySegue", sender: nil)
    }
    task.resume()

}
override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

var stuff: String!
var otherstuff: String!


override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if (segue.identifier == "calculateToDisplaySegue"){

        var svc = segue.destinationViewController as! PriceViewController;
        svc.dataPassed = self.stuff
        svc.secondDataPassed = self.otherstuff

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`stuff` and `otherstuff` are defined local to the method, not in the class instance variables.

IOW use:

```
self.stuff = parseJSON!.valueForKey("price")
self.otherstuff = parseJSON!.valueForKey("YlowestURL") as! NSString
```

Of course  `stuff` and `otherstuff` must be declared as ivars of the appropriate type in place of:

```
var stuff: String!
var otherstuff: String!
```

Comment: I see... I can't believe I missed that. However, I remember trying this, and it kept forcing an error. When I enter the self.stuff: NSString! = .... , it tells me consecutive statements in a line requires a semi-colon. Why would it be acting this way?

Comment: @petermaxstack: remove `: NSString!` that's for defining variable type when declaring it, not necessary here

Comment: Perfect! Nailed it! 

I still have awful object types lying around... I had to convert from Anyobject to NSNumber to Int to String...

Answer (score 0):

It seems you're redefining your class properties with local variables inside the handler. You should replace

```
var stuff: AnyObject! = parseJSON!.valueForKey("price")
var otherstuff: NSString! = parseJSON!.valueForKey("YlowestURL") as! NSString
```

by

```
self.stuff = parseJSON!.valueForKey("price") as! String
self.otherstuff = parseJSON!.valueForKey("YlowestURL") as! String
```